# Dataframe ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe (reportingDatesDf) which the head looks like this:

```
reportingDatesDf.index            unique_stock_id reporting_type
date                                     
2015-01-28  BBG.MTAA.STM.S         2014:A
2015-01-28  BBG.MTAA.STM.S        2014:S2
2015-01-28  BBG.MTAA.STM.S        2014:Q4
2014-10-29  BBG.MTAA.STM.S        2014:C3
2014-10-29  BBG.MTAA.STM.S        2014:Q3
```

I am trying to reduce the dataframe to include entries that are only between 2 dates with the following line:

```
 reportingDatesDf = reportingDatesDf[(reportingDatesDf.index >= startDate) and (reportingDatesDf.index <= endDate)]
```

The dataframe is created from a CSV using the following code:

```
def getReportingDatesData(rawStaticDataPath,startDate,endDate):
    pattern = 'ReportingDates'+ '.csv'
    staticPath = rawStaticDataPath

    with open(staticPath+pattern,'rt') as f:

         reportingDatesDf = pd.read_csv(f, 
                 header=None,
                 usecols=[0,1,2],
                 parse_dates=[1],
                 dayfirst=True,
                 index_col=[1],
                 names=['unique_stock_id','date','reporting_type'])       
         #print(reportingDatesDf.head())
         print('reportingDatesDf.index',reportingDatesDf)      
         reportingDatesDf = reportingDatesDf[(reportingDatesDf.index >= startDate) and (reportingDatesDf.index <= endDate)]
```

I however get the error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Could someone let me know why this has happened as I am using similar code else where which works and how to rectify the problem please.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`and` doesn't broadcast. It can't, because it has to short-circuit, and there's no good answer for making the short-circuiting broadcast.

If you need to do an elementwise `and`, you should use `&` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like in the line

```
reportingDatesDf = reportingDatesDf[(reportingDatesDf.index >= startDate) and (reportingDatesDf.index <= endDate)]
```

the variable

```
reportingDatesDf.index
```

is an array.  Thus, saying

```
(reportingDatesDf.index >= startDate)
```

is ambiguous.  You need to specify whether you are checking if *all* of the values in the array are greater than startDate, or if it contains *any* values greater than startDate.  Editing your code to the following

```
reportingDatesDf = reportingDatesDf[any(reportingDatesDf.index >= startDate) and any(reportingDatesDf.index <= endDate)]
```

or

```
reportingDatesDf = reportingDatesDf[all(reportingDatesDf.index >= startDate) and all(reportingDatesDf.index <= endDate)]
```

should fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I get a KeyError: True error when I implement the code, Does this mean I'm possibly missing some data somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
reportingDatesDf = reportingDatesDf[(reportingDatesDf.index >= startDate) and (reportingDatesDf.index <= endDate)]
```

to this:

```
reportingDatesDf = reportingDatesDf[(reportingDatesDf.index >= startDate) & (reportingDatesDf.index <= endDate)]
```

In other words, user the proper operator ;)